# Save php output into variable when using fsockopen

Tags: php, telnet, fsockopen, fputs

I'm trying to build a php script, which connects to a telnet server and runs a few commands.

I would like to save the returned output of a command into a variable.

Example:
Command: Give me a number!
The server returns a number.. lets say it is 100.
I would like to save the number 100 as variable.

Here is my source code:

```
<?php  
# connecting
$fp=fsockopen("10.73.xxx.xxx",23);

# login
fputs($fp,"\r");
sleep(1);
fputs($fp,"user\r");
sleep(1);
fputs($fp,"password\r");

# commands
fputs($fp,"give me a number!\n");  //this returns the number I would like to save as variable

sleep(1);

fclose($fp);
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want **[`stream_get_line`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-get-line.php)**

```
$theData = stream_get_line($fp, 1024, "\n");
// 1024 = The maximum number of bytes to read from the handle.
// \n = string delimiter.
```